# NPM Deep Email Validator, Reason timeout

Tags: node.js, email-validation

I am using npm package deep-email-validator in my node project.
But when i try to check emails, sometimes it show me the error as

```
{"message":"Please provide a valid email address.","reason":"Timeout"}
```

But when I send mail to same email address from gmail account, it got successful.

My code:

```
const { valid, reason, validators } = await isEmailValid(mailchk); async function isEmailValid(email) { return emailValidator.validate(email) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the additional top-level domains array? maybe you haven't included the domain you need, for example, in my project, the default wasn't set to accept "com.br" which is a common address suffix in my country... Maybe that'll solve it.